# Pattern matching

Tags: c++, pattern-matching

I was just wondering if any other logic is possible for this problem:
     Question : Find the number of pairs in a given string and output the sum of all the pairs and the unpaired elements. PS: The input is case sensitive.

Example O/P:

eeqe  3

aaaa
2

rwertr
5

I figured out the solution to this problem by first sorting the input string and then comparing adjacent elements as shown in the code below:

```
int main()
{
int t,count=0,pos=0;
char swap;
    char a[201];
    cin>>a;
    int len=strlen(a);
    //cout<<a<<endl;
    for (int c = 0 ; c < ( len - 1 ); c++)
    {
for (int d = 0 ; d < len - c - 1; d++)
{
  if (a[d] > a[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
  {
    swap       = a[d];
    a[d]   = a[d+1];
    a[d+1] = swap;
  }
}
}
    //cout<<a<<endl;
    count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<len;){
        if(a[i]==a[i+1]){
            count++;
            i+=2;
            //if(i== len-2)i++;
        }
        else{ count++; i++;}
    }
    //if(a[len-1]!=a[len-2])count++;
    cout<<count<<endl;
return 0;
```

}

This code works fine. But, I was just wondering if there is any other efficient solution to this problem that doesn't involve sorting the entire input array.

Comment: You don't specify any rules for pairs...

Comment: What do you mean by "the number of pairs in a given string"? Do you mean pairs of characters? Do they have to be adjacent to be considered a "pair"?

Comment: Are you counting [2-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram)?

Comment: I imagine to find all 'pairs' efficiently you'll need sorting. Note that there are many more efficient sorting algorithms than the way you did it (e.g. merge sort or quick sort) (look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm), I believe what you did was insertion sort).

Comment: I take it a 'pair' means any two identical characters. So, in the examples above, the pairs would be e+e for the first, a+a and a+a for the second and r+r for the third.

Comment: Yup, @Dukeling is right. The elements considered to be a pair needn't be adjacent to each other. And yeah, I know that there are efficient sorting algorithms available, but I'm just trying to eliminate the process of sorting. Is there any other way possible that doesn't use sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically avoids sorting based on the idea that there are only 256 possible chars, so it's sufficent to count them.This is my solution:

```
int main()
{
  std::string s; std::cin >> s;
  int cnt[256] = {};
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
    ++cnt[static_cast<unsigned char>(s[i])];
  int sum = 0;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    sum += cnt[i]/2 + cnt[i]%2;
  std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}
```

If, for example, the string contains 5 times an `'a'`, this allows 5/2 pairs (integer division) and 1 remains unpaired (because 5 is odd => 5%2 is 1)

Edit: Because we are here in SO:

```
int main()
{
  std::array<int, 256> cnt{-1}; // last char will be '\0', ignore this.
  std::for_each(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(std::cin.rdbuf()),
                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{},
                [&](unsigned char c){++cnt[c];});
  std::cout << std::accumulate(cnt.begin(), cnt.end(), 0,
                               [](int i, int c)->int{return i+(c/2)+(c%2);}) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: What is a "pair" in a string?

Comment: "pair" means two equal characters (at least it's what I understood, and it seems to hold in the examples given).

Comment: There are 5 equal characters in rwertr?

Comment: That's an example. In rwertr is 1 pair of r's and 4 single characters, this gives 5 in sum.

Comment: I would use `sum = ::std::accumulate(cnt, cnt+256), 0, [](int c) -> int { return int(c / 2) + c % 2; });` - Then I would also change it to `int cnt[256] = {};`.

Comment: @EtienneCordonnier "output the sum of all the pairs and the unpaired elements". r+r is one pair, there are 4 unpaired elements.

Comment: Yes! Use **all** the features! _grin_ But why initialize with `-1`? - Oh, I see. The -1 is not replicated and the rest are left at 0. That makes sense.

Comment: yes, in 'rwertr', a total of 3 r's are present. So, you pair two r's and consider the other as a separate instance that can't find itself another r to pair up with.